# Removing duplicate values in two columns while keeping the row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 A    1    ABC  XYZ  ZZZ
 A    1    XYZ  YYY  KKK
 B    2    JJJ  KKK  LLL
 B    2    OOO  ASD  FGH
 C    3    TFG  KLO  PLJ
```

I need to remove the values from `col1` and `col2` if the value in the same columns of next row is equal to the previous. Also I need to preserve the values of the same row in other columns.

I have tried using `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1','col2'])` but it removes the whole row pertaining to the duplicated value. `series.drop_duplicates()` doesn't have the `subset` parameter to remove the duplicates considering multiple columns. I have also comparing using `shift(-1)` which doesn't seem to be working.

Result df:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 A    1    ABC  XYZ  ZZZ
           XYZ  YYY  KKK
 B    2    JJJ  KKK  LLL
           OOO  ASD  FGH
 C    3    TFG  KLO  PLJ
```

Should I use the `for loop` to loop through row cells to find duplicates or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with set value by mask in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
c = ['col1','col2']
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=c), c] = ''
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0    A    1  ABC  XYZ  ZZZ
1            XYZ  YYY  KKK
2    B    2  JJJ  KKK  LLL
3            OOO  ASD  FGH
4    C    3  TFG  KLO  PLJ
```